# What is the condition to be banned by the network in NEAR?

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

It seems that there is a threshold to be kicked out from the validators on the epoch after the next, but it seems that you can get banned at the current epoch for not producing enough blocks. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are multiple ways to get banned. For example, if you produced a block with invalid signature, your node will get banned. Alternatively, your node can get banned if you signal a peer that you have headers for them to sync from but do not actually give them headers at a reasonable speed.

Comment: Can a validator get banned if their node does not produce enough blocks (e.g. the node is offline) during the current epoch? Will it reduce the number of skipped blocks? Will it improve blocks production?